C++ - Windows time behavior and setLocalTime from sysinfoapi.h
I have a strange behavior in Windows, my question is kinda similar to this one. Procedure to get the bug is quite simple. If I set the time to a past date regarding the last valid shutdown on Windows with SetLocalTime() in my application, when I powercut the device, the time goes back to the last valid shutdown time. Additional information:
NTP service is off;
W32time service is off;
No sort of automatic syncronization is enabled.
This bug is even able to reproduce in normal PC. just disable automatic sync on Windows to make sure the time is not being adjusted by Windows time service. procedure is as below:

Check the time on system, let's say e.g. 2024-Dec-09 - 09:00:00
Boot up your PC in BIOS and change the time to e.g. 2023-Dec-09 - 16:00:00.
Boot on Windows Again
Check Windows time, notice that time is not the one you set in BIOS, but the time you shutdown your system before.

This is a service for an embedded device driver that will be in field and can be power cut at any time. So, in this case answers like making Windows shutdown properly doesn't help. Also, because of it being embedded device, there's no internet connection or some sort of NTP server. Due to that the device needs to rely on the CMOS RTC clock.
Last extra information, Time is being set on CMOS After the power cut. I checked that on a Linux based OS after doing a power cut and the time set on past from Windows is really there.
Has anyone experienced some sort of similar symptom?
Edit: Moving time forward from BIOS naturally has no problems after power cut.

Apparently Windows automatically sets the RTC time to the time of the last shutdown if the RTC time is totally off or not plausible. What happens if you boot up your PC in BIOS and change the time to a time that is only slightly off the time during the last shutdown?

I can check that tomorrow on the device. It seem kinda like it, but it was really something we're not expecting. I always thought Windows would show CMOS time. And the biggest problem is that when it does it, it also overwrite the time on RTC.

If the devices are up to it you could maybe boot into a Linux system and run Windows in a VM.

that's cool idea, but we don't have virtualization enabled on this device and no chance to change it on BIOS. @JonathanPotter

@Jabberwocky I did test like you suggested and it didn't work I found this link saying this is a Windows default behavior. But it didn't mention anything about Power cuts when you change time from inside Windows.
